# What variant of logistic regression is correct here?

Tags: logistic, multilevel-analysis, hierarchical-bayesian

Here is my setup:

- I have `M=200` municipalities who all rank high in corruption
- For each municipality, I pick a random sample of `N=100` employees from the city government
- I ask these people a dichotomous `Y = 1/0` question, with slight variations `v1, v2, v3, v4` such that 25 people are assigned to `v1`... 25 to `v4` etc
- I control for a vector of `X_m` municipality characteristics (e.g: size, population, etc)

I want to build a model predicting whether a given person will say yes to the question. And further, I want to recover specific intercepts for:

- Each of the municipalities
- Each of the question variants

Is this a case for Bayesian multilevel logit? Simple mixed logit? etc

Comment: Tell us more about your data. Are those all existing municipalities or just a sample? The 100 people from each municipality are a random sample? What is the purpose of your analysis?

Comment: I edited it. And the thing I forgot to add is there are slight variants of the question too